# c# change GET implementation get<typed>() to get()

Tags: c#, .net

I have some problem I can not resolve.

I have a class `GlobalTest` derived from `GlobalObjectImpl`:

```
public class GlobalTest : GlobalObjectImpl
{
        public string LastProcessDay { get; set; }
}
```

It was called from this:

```
var global = GlobalTest.Get<GlobalTest>();
```

The `GlobalObjectImpl` is declared like this:

```
public abstract class GlobalObjectImpl
{
    public bool Save()
    {
        return DataStore.SaveGlobal(this);
    }
    public static T Get<T>() where T : GlobalObjectImpl
    {
        return DataStore.GetGlobal<T>();
    }
}
```

I want to get my `LastProceedDate` like this:

```
var global = GlobalTest.Get();
```

But it fails.

Comment: How would that work? What type would it return?

Comment: You can't. The compiler can only infer the generic type from _input parameters_.

Comment: Do the abstract class compile without error? Where the abstract methods?

Comment: @M.Hassan you do not need an abstract class to have abstract methods in order to compile

Comment: @SLaks, type result expected is GlobalTest object and i want the property LastProcessDay

Answer (score 0):

You can make your abstract class generic like the following:

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    public static T Get() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived> { }
```

And then just call `Get`

```
var foo = Derived.Get();
```

Comment: public class Derived : Base<Derived> { }, can you explain this ?

Comment: It is just a class that implements abstract class `Base<T>`. Just like your `GlobalTest` implements `GlobalObject`. I made it an Empty class since the only need required for explaining the question is the static `Get()` method defined in the base class

Answer (score 0):

I all, big thank to you, i have succesfully implemented my class

My Abstract Class

```
public abstract class GlobalTreeObjectImpl<T>
{
    public bool Save()
    {
        return NeoStore.SaveGlobal(this);
    }

public static T Get() => NeoStore.GetGlobal<T>();
    }
}
```

Class use abstract class

```
public class GlobalTest : GlobalTreeObjectImpl<GlobalAntai>
{
    public string LastProcessDay { get; set; }
}
```

Usage of this on my code

```
        var global = GlobalTest.Get();

        LoggerManager.LogInfo($"Global LastProcessDay : {global.LastProcessDay} - {DateTime.UtcNow}");

        global.LastProcessDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThhh:mmm:ssZ");
        global.Save();

        global = GlobalTest.Get();

        LoggerManager.LogInfo($"Global LastProcessDay : {global.LastProcessDay} - {DateTime.UtcNow}");
```